# Control 2x relay module (STM8S103) from ESP01

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have this module http://www.chinalctech.com/xwzx/24.html (two relays version) and trying to control it from ESP01.

I have reflashed the default ESP firmware with my code, but I am not sure how to control the relays.

In the documentation of the relay board I have found these instructions:

```
Control command for relay （hex format ）：
Open relay 1 ：A0 01 01 A2
Close relay 1 ：A0 01 00 A1
Open relay 2 ：A0 02 01 A3
Close relay 2：A0 02 00 A2
Open relay 3 ：A0 03 01 A4
Close relay 3 ：A0 03 00 A3
Open relay 4 ：A0 04 01 A5
Close relay 4 ：A0 04 00 A4
```

But I am not sure where to put these instructions. I have tried to send them using serial like this:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop() {
    char bb[] = {0xA0, 0x01, 0x01, 0xA2};
    Serial.write(bb);

    delay(1500);

    char bb1[] = {0xA0, 0x01, 0x00, 0xA1};
    Serial.write(bb1);

    delay(1500);

    char bb2[] = {0xA0, 0x02, 0x01, 0xA3};
    Serial.write(bb2);

    delay(1500);

    char bb3[] = {0xA0, 0x02, 0x00, 0xA2};
    Serial.write(bb3);
    delay(1500);
}
```

But no changes on the relays.

So the question is, how to control the onboard relays from ESP01? I don't want to use the Android app or other built in functions that came with the board, I just want to know the raw command to open/close relays.

Comment: `Serial.write(bb, sizeof(bb));`

Comment: @Juraj Thankujem, didn't realize that the array is not null terminated .. but it didn't solve my problem :( Looks like some wiring issue ... I can't even get it to work by using USB serial adapter and sending the instructions directly to the board (omiting ESP)